# Proving Natural Numbers as Irrational

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, irrational-numbers

For which natural numbers *n*, is 
√ *n* 
 irrational? Prove your answer.

Comment: What have you tried, and where did you get stuck? Don't just ask us to do your homework for you.

Comment: I was not asking for you to do my homework for me, I did not know how to start. I figured it out thanks anyway.